# No transport supports the given Messenger DSN doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-messenger

I am getting an error `No transport supports the given Messenger DSN "doctrine://default"` when executing command `messenger:setup-transports` for Symfony messenger.

Handling messages synchronously for the message, handler, and dispatcher works.

Symfony: `4.4.2`

Symfony/messenger: `4.4`

doctrine/orm: `2.7`

`messenger.yml`

```
    messenger:
        default_bus: messenger.bus.default

        transports:
            async: 'doctrine://default'
```

`doctrine.yml`

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver: "%database_driver%"
                port: "%database_port%"
                host: "%database_host%"
                dbname: "%database_name%"
                user: "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
```

Comment: im facing the same issue
symfony/framework-bundle 4.3.7
symfony/messenger: 4.3.9
doctrine/orm 2.7.x-dev